# Oracle: Find sum of a VARCHAR2(50 byte) column

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, format, varchar2

I have to calculate the sum of `VARCHAR2(50 byte)` column in my Oracle database.

The SQL query is:

`SELECT city, sum(forests) as sum_forests FROM BurnedAreas GROUP BY city`

The column `forests` has datatype `VARCHAR2(50 byte)`

I've tried already some functions but they didn't work:

1. `TO_NUMBER()`
2. `CAST()`

I believe the problem is that the values of the specific column have different format. Some values are like 5.37, others like 14,23 etc.

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: Does the comma represent a decimal point?

Comment: Yes, in both situations the dot and comma represents the decimal point.

Comment: So how many different formats are there in this column? You say that the decimal separator is sometimes a comma, sometimes a point. Can there be thousand separators, too? Can there be other values, such as 'two', 'none', 'n.a.', '  ' or the like?

Comment: And hopefully you learn from this and change your column's data type to decimal :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Or at the very least, use a consistent locale for the numbers.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: And write a constraint to reject invalid number strings? Possible, but quite a pain, I'd say :-)

Comment: UPDATE: I checked the values and I found thousands separator too. There is also a value with 2 commas like 1,404,27 and other with comma and dot like 1,590.42.

Comment: Given that your data is in such a poor state, I would recommend that you fix the source of your data.  Handling this in Oracle is probably going to require a very ugly and complex regex replacement.

Comment: I understand! Thanks for the quick responses

Comment: I fixed the values inside DB with one format. Now all values have comma as  decimal separator and dot as thousands separator. For example: 5,00 - 130,00 - 4.000,00 - 150.200.000,00. In function to_number() what's the specific format mask ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned the data in the VARCHAR column had a format like 4.900,25 where dot was hundred separator and comma decimal separator (2 decimal digits).

So to find the sum, I used `TO_NUMBER` function with **some more parameters**.

`SUM(TO_NUMBER(forests,'999G999G999D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''))`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT city,sum(to_number(replace(translate(forests, '(', '-'), ')', ''))) AS sum_forests
FROM BurnedAreas
GROUP BY city

Generally one need to check how the data flow is there for "forests" column.
Accordingly need to include the condition inside translate(...)

Hope that helps!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will skip non numeric data and you will not get error.

```
SELECT city, sum(forests) as sum_forests 
FROM BurnedAreas 
where ISNUMERIC (forests)=1
GROUP BY city
```

OR

Insert all data in temp table & then do sum. becuase your column having "," which is making value invalid.

```
SELECT city, replace(forests,',','') as forests 
 into #BurnedAreas
 FROM BurnedAreas
```

Then run below data.

```
SELECT city, sum(forests) as sum_forests 
FROM #BurnedAreas 
GROUP BY city
```

Comment: But this is a bit like throwing the baby out with the bathwater, because then the sum would not reflect the true logical value.